# Git Dropping Commits Between Client GUI & Server

Tags: git, github

Last night, I was coding at the optimal time of 1 AM, which ended up causing some not so optimal git behavior (and I also now regret even more using the git GUI rather than command line, but that's another tale).

I had just composed a commit locally through the desktop tool and hit the "sync" button to push to master. At this moment, being the middle of the night, my ISP decided to cut my internet for 10 mins. The sync timed out, as expected. Once my connection resumed, I went to retry pushing the commit, but, locally, the GUI indicated that the commit had already been pushed. I switched to the command line tool and double checked with a `git status` and, sure enough, no files modified.

However, when I visit [my repository](https://github.com/mattkgross/WorkoutLogPro), I do not see the commit or the changes applied to my files. If I try (online) to edit either of the files from my failed commit, it gives me an error simply stating "File could not be edited." What is more odd is that my desktop tool Commit History links to [the commit](https://github.com/mattkgross/WorkoutLogPro/commit/8347c31c020364dbaad305178197681de421df8d), even though it was not applied to the repository or otherwise showing on GitHub.

It appears that my commit is in some weird state between being pushed and actually being applied. I'm wondering if anyone has experienced anything similar and found a fix to this or has any ideas about how to at least unlock the affected files and then reapply my changes.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by granting write permissions to my readonly files and adding an edit to each. I then committed this change and successfully pushed the commit which, in turn, caused the commit for 22 hours ago, along with its changes, to finally be applied on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Using the commandline (or maybe the GUI too if it offers something) change directories to the repo and do "git fetch". This shall refresh the cache for the remote state and then allow you to retry the push.

Comment: Unfortunately, doing so did not change anything. Commit still appears submitted locally, but not on GitHub's codebase.

Comment: Try cloning the repo again, to a different place, then resubmitting the commits. This is a not-really-nice workaround but if this doesn't work either then it's quite a messup.